# How can I set one onOpen function for several sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I have a workbook with 6 similar sheets. And I have one script which helps me to protect the rows according to date in column A. Each row has a date. The rows are sorted according to the date, and we add information with a new date and data almost every day. When the date is before today, the row becomes protected, so we can enter new info in the row with current date and the future.

[image: The sheet with protected rows]

So, for today the yellow rows are protected. Here is the link for the [worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qg2vN1HVe2WillcU9XceeipaxBUMtl29QNu02XcV7VI/edit?usp=sharing).

The script I use:

```
    function onOpen(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ISKUR");
  var dateRange = sh.getRange(6, 1, sh.getLastRow()-2, 1);
  var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "MM/dd/YYYY");
  var protectRow;
  //check if date is less than the current date
  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
    if(val[i][0]>=curDate){
      protectRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  var protection = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  //If protection exists, update else add new one.
  if(protection.length > 0){
    var range = sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 13);
    protection[0].setRange(range);
  }else{
    sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 13).protect();
  }
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dateRange = sh.getRange(6, 1, sh.getLastRow()-2, 1);
  var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "MM/dd/YYYY");
  var protectRow;
  //check if date is less than the current date
  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
    if(val[i][0]>=curDate){
      protectRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  var protection = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  //If protection exists, update else add new one.
  if(protection.length > 0){
    var range = sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 13);
    protection[0].setRange(range);
  }else{
    sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 13).protect();
  }
}
```

It seems that it doesn't work correctly for several pages. How can I protect rows using this script in several sheets, if all of them have a similar structure (date in column A)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

You can't have multiple `onOpen` triggers.

### Solutions:

**Solution 1 (recommended): execute your code for multiple sheets like that:**

This code assumes you can run the **same** code for every sheet you specify in the `sheetNames` array:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = ['ISKUR','Sheet1']; // put the names of the sheets you want to run the script
  
  sheetNames.forEach(name=>{ 
         var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
         var dateRange = sh.getRange(6, 1, sh.getLastRow()-2, 1);
         var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
         var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "MM/dd/YYYY");
         var protectRow;
         //check if date is less than the current date
         for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
            if(val[i][0]>=curDate){
            protectRow = i;
            break;
            }
         }  
        var protection = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
       //If protection exists, update else add new one.
       if(protection.length > 0){
         var range = sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 13);
         protection[0].setRange(range);
       }else{
       sh.getRange(6, 1, protectRow, 13).protect();
       }                          
  });
}
```

**Solution 2: create multiple functions for every sheet:**

This solution is recommended in case you want to run **different** code for different sheets:

```
function onOpen(e){
  onOpen1(e);
  onOpen2(e);
}

function onOpen1(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // rest of the code
}

function onOpen2(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ISKUR");
  // rest of the code
}
```

That solution becomes handy in case different sheets have different structure or you want to apply a unique logic for individual sheets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! The first solution is working. And I will surely use the second variant for another sheet!